# Checking and passing parameters runtime to a method in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

How can I check the required parameters (type, name and order) of a function in c#?

What I want to do is the following:

Within a method, I have 4 variables of different types (double, int, string, enum etc.). All these variables need to be passed to a suitable function (I mean method). There are three candidate functions each requiring different set of parameters.

The code must check which function has 4 input parameters with exactly matching types, and pass my variables to this function. My method should create an exception if no matching function is found. Thanks in advance for any help.

Serena

Comment: Do you have any code so far?  It would be helpful to see what you've already tried

Comment: Any reason you can't do this at run-time, i.e., let the compiler bind the methods for you, based on their signatures?

Comment: You already have 4 variables. And you know their types. What is the problem? Do you think variable type can change suddenly?

Comment: No, I now that it has got to do with "reflection" but I haven't yet written any code. I am rather a c# beginner, I did almost everything with R before.

Comment: Could you clarify when a different method would be instantiated.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you think variable type can change suddenly? The proper function to be applied depends on the available data. For example, if you have complete data for a product this means 6 parameters and the functions with 6 input parameters must be called. On the other hand, the list of available functions for each product group also change dynamically.

Comment: @selmar it is quite a complex task for a C# beginner... May I suggest you something like "Essential.NET" to start with? http://www.amazon.com/Essential-NET-Common-Language-Runtime/dp/0201734117
It contains an introduction to all the concepts you will need to face (IF the reflection path is the right choice!). It contains examples and code on how to walk assemblies and types.

Comment: @selmar - Can you explain *why* you need to do this?  There's probably an already-existing way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the parameters you are given are in the right order, then you can just see if each parameter is assignable from the type of the signature at that position, and it's not all that bad:

```
public static MethodInfo CallMethod(MethodInfo[] candicateMethods, object instance, object[] parameters)
{
    foreach (var method in candicateMethods)
    {
        if (CallMethod(method, instance, parameters))
            return method;
    }
    return null;
}

private static bool CallMethod(MethodInfo method, object instance, object[] parameters)
{
    if (method.GetParameters().Length == parameters.Length
        && method.GetParameters()
        .Zip(parameters, (a, b) => new
        {
            Signature = a.ParameterType,
            Candidate = b.GetType()
        })
        .All(pair => pair.Signature.IsAssignableFrom(pair.Candidate)))
    {
        method.Invoke(instance, parameters);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you also need to deal with out/ref/params/etc. in the signature, it will get much more complex.

If the parameters aren't in the right order, then you need to attempt the `Zip`/`All` for each permutation of `parameters` (possibly cutting entire branches, which may be easier through a backtracking algorithm, but it's still potentially *very* time consuming).

Comment: If the code used to look for the correct method is used once (for example, caching the MethodInfo) or not so often, you can easily scan all the permutations of the (4) parameters without worrying about it being too time consuming

Comment: @dema80 It will be easy enough to code, but it will be *horribly* time consuming if there is more than a tiny number of parameters.  Even 5 or parameters results in **120** permutations, each of which needs to compare each parameter with each potential parameter.  This results in O((n^2)!) time.  That's **horrible**.  Now if you have 6 or 7 parameters this becomes a very, very difficult problem.  Now sure, if you have just 1 or 2, it's fine, but that's about it.

Comment: of course, I would never do it in a compiler, or even in code that it is not ad-hoc for the given problem, but based on the number of parameters given by the OP (4) I would say it is ok, being only 24 permutations. Even 5 should be OK (generating and scanning an array/IEnumerable of 120 elements it's not so bad). more... I agree, it's not viable.

Comment: @dema80 It's not that your scanning a single enumerable of that many elements, it's that you have 120 enumerations, each of which need to be scanned.  That makes the problem that much worse.  If you *know* that there are never more than 4 parameters, it may be feasible, but if there can be *any* more the runtime will spike up very quickly (about as quickly as any algorithm I've ever seen).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("test");

        string parameterTypes = string.Join(", ", method.GetParameters().Select(x=>x.ParameterType));

        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})",                             
                          method.Name,
                          parameterTypes);


        Console.ReadKey();
    }



    public void test(int a, string c)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This code checks the specific method's name and parameters

Answer (score -1):

(as the question asks for "runtime" matching (vs.compile time), and it is tagged with reflection, I will answer keeping that in mind)

With reflection, you get all the information you need to make the decision based on types you mentioned. For example, MethodInfo contains two methods that may be relevant to you:

ReturnType:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype.aspx

GetParameters:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx

Once you have found the function you are looking for, you can invoke it using the.. Invoke method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx

Without a more specific example, the procedure is:

For all MethodInfo(s) in a class:

- get parameters and return type
- examine returntype (if needed)
- if the types in the parameters and return type match, done

As mentioned in the comments, the third point may be the hard part. It is what the compiler usually do when it picks the best matching overloaded method (i.e. when it selects from multiple methods with the same name, based only on the types).

However, your case may be mush simpler than the general problem: deciding if one of a finite number of methods, with a fixed number of parameters, with the requested types in order (and with the exact types, i.e. there is no need for implicit casts) can be implemented quite easily. You should provide more context.

If you have a valid methodinfo, pass the params as an object array to invoke.
Warning: reflection is not super efficient (it is not terribly slow, either!).
You should only do this if you really need it, in cases where a good OO design won't help you for example.

Comment: It's not exactly trivial to take the result of `GetParameters` along with a collection of objects and determine if those objects can be passed to that method (unless the collection of parameters is known to be in the proper order).  This is effectively doing method resolution, which is normally done by the compiler, and is rather complex.

Comment: I have not said it's trivial. It is almost like doing method resolution, even if it seems that the OP only needs exact matching (no overload, no implicit cast). In any case, the framework assists you with the Type class and its methods, like IsAssignableFrom

Comment: My point is that that's what he's asking for, and this is addressing such a tiny aspect of the problem and ignoring the hard part, which makes it pretty useless as an answer.

Comment: @Servy I see your point; that is why I pointed out that IF reflection turns out to be the way to go, using MethodInfo, GetParameters and IsAssignableFrom may help. Without more specific context, this is the best I could offer :)

Comment: I already did in my previous comment.  You don't actually answer the question.  The answer is not useful, it is incomplete (as in 95% of the answer is missing).  You think such an answer shouldn't be downvotted?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23239/discussion-between-dema80-and-servy)